# Calculating gradient at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> A differentiable scalar field f has, at the point (1, 2), directional derivatives +2 in the direction
> toward (2,2) and -2 in the direction toward (1, 1). Determine the gradient vector at (1, 2)
> and compute the directional derivative in the direction toward (4, 6).

This is a question from Tom Apostol Vol. 2.
My approach:
let $\nabla f(1,2) = (x,y)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla f(1,2) \cdot (2,2) &=& 2  \\
\therefore 2x+2y&=&2
\end{eqnarray*}
Also,
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla f(1,2) \cdot (1,1) &=& -2  \\
\therefore x+y&=&-2
\end{eqnarray}
These equations are inconsistent with each other.
What Mistake am I doing? Any help would be nice, Thanks

Comment: The directions towards $(2,2)$ and $(1,1)$ are the same, i.e. $\frac1{2\sqrt2}(2,2)=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1)$. The directional derivative can't differ along the same direction. The question has some problem (as you have kind of discovered).

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I know direction should be the same. Hence my question

Comment: Maybe the text means that the vector $\nabla f$ "attached" in the point $(1,2)$ has the component in the direction of the vector $(2,2)-(1,2)=(1,0)$ (i.e. the tip of the component _looks_ toward $(1,2)$) of $+2$ and the component in the direction of the vector $(1,1)-(1,2)=(0,-1)$ (i.e. the tip of the component _looks_ toward $(1,1)$) of $-2$. In that case $\nabla f \cdot (1,0)=2 , \nabla f \cdot (0,-1)=-2 \Rightarrow \nabla f =(2,2)$.

Comment: @Eigenket "Component" is not mentioned anywhere. Also directional derivative is defined as the component of gradient vector along a given vector. Taking the component of directional derivative does not make sense mathematically as well as intuitively

Comment: Where I talked about "component of directional derivative"? I only supposed that the text meant that $\nabla f \cdot (1,0)=2, \nabla f \cdot (0,-1) = -2$ i.e. partial derivatives are both $2$. I only supposed that the text meant direction toward $(2,2)$ with respect to the point $(1,2)$ and not with respect to the origin.

Comment: @Eigenket The text can't possibly mean that